# MIPS readint syscall not taking in inputs

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I have an assignment to write out a minimum int function in QTSpim. It seems that when I tried to put in 2 user inputs namely 0 and 4, it bypasses my input totally, and since my functions depend heavily on my user inputs, I am unable to test whether my code works. Can someone help me out with this issue? My code and correct expected output is as shown below.

```
# arrayFunction.asm
       .data 
array: .word 8, 2, 1, 6, 9, 7, 3, 5, 0, 4
newl:  .asciiz "\n"

       .text
main:
    addi $a1, $zero, 10
    li $v0, 4 # Print the original content of array
    la $a0, array
    la $a3, array #to store so that we can modify a0 later
    jal printArray # prints integer array


    # setup the parameter(s)
    # call the printArray function

    # Ask the user for two indices
    #li   $v0, 5            # System call code for read_int
    #syscall           
    #addi $t0, $v0, 0       # first user input in $t0

    #li   $v0, 5            # System call code for read_int
    #syscall           
    #addi $t1, $v0, 0       # second user input in $t1

    addi $t0, $zero, 0      # simulate first input
    addi $t1, $zero, 4.     # simulate 2nd input

    # Call the findMin function
    # setup the parameter(s)

    sll $t0, $t0, 2     #multiply by 4 to increment first pointer
    sll $t1, $t1, 2     #multiply by 4 to increment 2nd pointer
    add $a1, $t1, $a0   #make final address for larger pointer
    add $a0, $t0, $a0   #make final address for smaller pointer
    addi $t4, $zero, 99 #set the first lowest element to 99, magic number
    #modify arguments before sending in but actually its mutation

    jal findMin # call the function


    # Print the min item
    # place the min item in $t3 for printing

    # Print an integer followed by a newline
    li   $v0, 1         # system call code for print_int
    addi $a0, $t3, 0    # print $t3
    syscall             # make system call

    li   $v0, 4         # system call code for print_string
    la   $a0, newl      # 
    syscall             # print newline

    #Calculate and print the index of min item


    # Place the min index in $t3 for printing   
    sub $t3, $v0, $a3 
    srl $t3, $t3, 2
```

Here is the output I'm supposed to see on the console:

```
8216973504 #original array
0 #first user input
4 #2nd user input
1 #Min element
2 #index of element
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it bypasses my input totally"? PS: note you have an extra dot in `sll $t1, $t1, 4.` which may or may not cause problems. I'd delete it just to be sure.

Comment: Like it doesn't even seem to take it my input when I run 0 and 4

Comment: You can always debug the parts separately, e.g. by hardcoding some inputs with `li`.  Debug the parts after input-reading by single-stepping with the debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes Just a sanity check in case I'm not familiar with how QTSpim works. Do I press play for the first function `printArray` then type my inputs on 2 different lines then press play again or can I just do it at the start?

Comment: @Jester the dot was a typo when I was changing out some of the comments on SO for clarity purposes, my original code doesn't have that, but thanks for informing me.

Comment: I've never used QTSpim, just MARS.  I know QTSpim *has* a debugger, and I know SPIM lets you set breakpoints on any instruction.  So you can set breakpoints, examine registers and memory, and most importantly, single-step by 1 instruction and see what changed.  (i.e. which registers were changed by the previous instruction.)  These are key features that all debuggers share.  IDK what the buttons look like in the UI, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I solved some logic issues within my code and temporary got the readInt issue out of the way, can you tell me why am I getting a hexadecimal value of `A` for my first element when I'm expecting it to be `8`?

Comment: @PrashinJeevaganth because you either don't read first element (wrong address), or because some other code did overwrite the memory meanwhile (check memory view in debugger vs address of `array` vs address which you read).